# Finding the value of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } f\left( n \right)$ of a series having the value "n" in both numerator and denominator

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f\left( n \right) = n + \frac{{16 + 5n - 3{n^2}}}{{4n + 3{n^2}}} + \frac{{32 + n - 3{n^2}}}{{8n + 3{n^2}}} + \frac{{48 - 3n - 3{n^2}}}{{12n + 3{n^2}}} + .. + \frac{{25 - 7{n^2}}}{{7{n^2}}}$. Then find the value of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } f\left( n \right) = \_\_\_$

My approach is as follow

$f\left( n \right) = n + \frac{{16 + 5n - 3{n^2}}}{{4n + 3{n^2}}} + \frac{{32 + n - 3{n^2}}}{{8n + 3{n^2}}} + \frac{{48 - 3n - 3{n^2}}}{{12n + 3{n^2}}} + .. + \frac{{25 - 7{n^2}}}{{7{n^2}}}$

$16 + \left( {n' - 2} \right)16 = 16n' - 16::\left( {5 + \left( {n' - 2} \right)\left( { - 4} \right)} \right) = 13 - 4n'::4 + \left( {n - 2} \right)4 = 4n' - 4$

${T_{n'}} = \frac{{16n' - 16 + 13n - 4n'n - 3{n^2}}}{{4n'n - 4n + 3{n^2}}}$

How will I proceed form here

Comment: I don't get how $f(n)$ is defined.

Comment: What goes in the dots?

Comment: Anyway....If we take the "squares over power" argument for each of the $\frac {c + dn -kn^2}{e+fn+kn^2} \to -1$ so the whole function $\to n -1 -1 -1.... -1$ and if I assume there are a set finite number of terms then $\to \infty$.  Although if the dots are somehow supposed to be $n$ terms or $n\pm b$ terms the limit is $0$ or $\mp b$.

Comment: "16+(n′−2)16=16n′−16::(5+(n′−2)(−4))=13−4n′::4+(n−2)4=4n′−4"  I have no idea what you are trying to do here or where any of this comes from.  "${T_{n'}} = \frac{{16n' - 16 + 13n - 4n'n - 3{n^2}}}{{4n'n - 4n + 3{n^2}}}$"  What on earth is $T_{n'}$ and where did it come from.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(n) =  \sum_{r =1}^n (1 +  \frac{16r + (9-4r)n -3n^2}{4rn + 3n^2}) $

$  =  \sum_{r =1}^n ( \frac{16r +9n}{4rn +3n^2} ) \\ $

$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} ( \sum_{r =1}^n ( \frac{ 16(\frac{r}{n}) +9}{4(\frac{r}{n}) +3}) )$

$ = \int_{0}^1  \frac{16x +9}{4x+3} dx$
$ = 4 + \frac{3}{4} ln \frac{3}{7} $

Comment: How did you figure $f(n) =  \sum_{r =1}^n (1 +  \frac{16r + (9-4r)n -3n^2}{4rn + 3n^2})$?